# C# OS Loader lock Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx

In VS 2008 when I try to step into the

```
return new Triangles(element, mesh);
```

line, I get the following error the first time

DLL 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

After the first time stepping through the code, I do not get any warnings and everything works great.

In 2010 when I get to the same line, the program hangs on the first time through (just like the warning states can happen in 2008)

There are no DirectX calls that I am aware of around this area.  How can I better debug this issue and what do I need to do to resolve it?

Thanks

- Answer -
  Hopefully this will help some other people.  I was able to get my solution in VS 2010 to work like the VS 2008 solution by creating an app.config file.

  ```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a [known problem](http://www.thezbuffer.com/articles/304.aspx) with DirectX... [from 2004](http://www.thezbuffer.com/articles/386.aspx).

Install the [latest version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937788.aspx) of the DirectX SDK and you should be good to go.

Comment: With the latest DirectX SDK installed I still get the warning and that is OK.  The problem is that in 2010, I do not even get the Loader Lock warning, the program just hangs.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I was able to find the answer and it is now edited in my question.  Thanks for looking into it.